# How to uninstall orphan Perl packages?

Tags: arch-linux, perl

`pacman` this morning reported the following:

> WARNING: '/usr/lib/perl5/5.28' contains data from at least 4 packages
>   which will NOT be used by the installed perl interpreter.   -> Run the
>   following command to get a list of affected packages: pacman -Qqo
>   '/usr/lib/perl5/5.28'

That command lists a few directories. I managed to find out which modules these are using `cpan -l`, but `cpanm` refuses to [uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626449/how-can-i-de-install-a-perl-module-installed-via-cpan) any of them. For example:

> ! Test::CleanNamespaces is not found in the following directories and
>   can't be uninstalled.
>
> /usr/lib/perl5/5.30/site_perl     /usr/share/perl5/site_perl

How do I remove these packages?

Comment: 5.28 != 5.30. It seems like you installed a new version of Perl, leaving the modules of the old version behind.

Comment: @choroba Yes, that's what happens when updating :) If there is a sensible (as in, automatable) way of dealing with this *before* upgrading that would be handy as well.

Comment: If you don't use 5.28 anymore, just remove all its directories.

Comment: Do you want to make that an answer? It answers my question very nicely :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5.28 != 5.30. It seems like you installed a new version of Perl, leaving the modules of the old version behind. If you don't use 5.28 anymore, just remove all its directories.